# Scada-LTS new UI access through a reverse-proxy

Tags: reverse-proxy

I have a reverse-proxy setup for a scada-LTS instance running in a docker container.   The legacy UI works correctly but when accessing the new UI, I see the following message in the browser console log: `Failed to establish WebSocket connection`.  Has anyone experienced and hopefully solved this issue?

Accessing the scada-LTS instance directly using a docker port remap, e.g. `ports: "8085:8080"` works correctly so it is something, possibly a missing header that fails with the reverse-proxy.

Comment: Determined the root cause of this.  The Scada-LTS console attempts to parse the `Host` header into an address and port in order to build the websocket URL.  My reverse proxy was using port 80 and the browser automatically removes this leaving the header as: `Host: scadalts.domain`.  In this case the websocket address is computed as: `http://scadalts.domain:undefined/Scada-LTS/ws-scada/alarmLevel`.  
My workaround was to change the reverse-proxy address from 80 to 8080 and it works.  Submitting an issue to scada-LTS as the port should be optional.